# HTML template doesn't display passed variables (Flask)

Tags: python, html, flask

I pass the variable with render_template() and the html outputs empty space in place of the variable.

Here's my flask code based on  a tutorial:

```
#import Flask 
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

#create an instance of Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predict/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #get form data
        tv = request.form.get('tv')
        radio = request.form.get('radio')
        newspaper = request.form.get('newspaper')
        return render_template('predict.html')

        #call preprocessDataAndPredict and pass inputs
        try:
            prediction = preprocessDataAndPredict(tv, radio, newspaper)        #pass prediction to template
            return render_template('predict.html', my_prediction = prediction)
        except ValueError:
            return "Please Enter valid values"
        pass
    
    pass

def preprocessDataAndPredict(tv, radio, newspaper):    #put all inputs in array
    test_data = [tv, radio, newspaper]
    print(test_data)    #convert value data into numpy array
    test_data = np.array(test_data).astype(np.float)    #reshape array
    test_data = test_data.reshape(1,-1)
    print(test_data)    #open file
    file = open("lr_model.pkl","rb")    #load trained model
    trained_model = joblib.load(file)    #predict
    prediction = trained_model.predict(test_data)
    return prediction
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the predict.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Prediction </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-5 pl-3">
            <p>Prediction is {{ my_prediction }}</p>
        </div>    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried passing simple, hardcoded variables but the target html only displays "Prediction is" and doesn't show any passed variable.
I'll appreciate every suggestion on how to fix this!

Edit: also attaching the home.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Predict Sales </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-5 pl-3">
            <h1>Predict Sales</h1>
        </div>        <!-- Starts form section -->
        <div class="form-container ">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action = "/predict/" method="post">                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tv">TV:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tv" name="tv">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="radio">Radio:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">          
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="radio" name="radio">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="newspaper">Newspaper:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newspaper" name="newspaper">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row"> 
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="">&nbsp;</label>                
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Predict</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            <!-- Ends form section -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html><!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Predict Sales </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-5 pl-3">
            <h1>Predict Sales</h1>
        </div>        <!-- Starts form section -->
        <div class="form-container ">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action = "/predict/" method="post">                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tv">TV:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tv" name="tv">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="radio">Radio:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">          
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="radio" name="radio">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="newspaper">Newspaper:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newspaper" name="newspaper">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row"> 
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="">&nbsp;</label>                
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Predict</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            <!-- Ends form section -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you always return

```
    return render_template('predict.html')
```

When you POST something and you never reach the return with the value you have later.

Overall you need to handle what is happening when you do not have a POST request, in your case a GET that is which will render the initial html. And when something is submitted you should render or redirect the html with the values you want.

**EDIT** After some clarifications you gave

Please check below:

home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Predict Sales </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-5 pl-3">
            <h1>Predict Sales</h1>
        </div>        <!-- Starts form section -->
        <div class="form-container ">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action = "/predict/" method="post">                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tv">TV:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tv" name="tv">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="radio">Radio:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">          
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="radio" name="radio">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="newspaper">Newspaper:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newspaper" name="newspaper">
                  </div>
                </div>                <div class="form-group row"> 
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="">&nbsp;</label>                
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Predict</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            <!-- Ends form section -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html><!doctype html>
```

I removed the duplicate form to check only with one set of inputs.

predict.html is the same

flask code:

```
#import Flask 
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

#create an instance of Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/predict/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #get form data
        tv = request.form.get('tv')
        radio = request.form.get('radio')
        newspaper = request.form.get('newspaper')

        prediction = preprocessDataAndPredict(tv, radio, newspaper)
        return render_template('predict.html', my_prediction = prediction)
    
    pass


def preprocessDataAndPredict(tv, radio, newspaper):    #put all inputs in array
    # test_data = [tv, radio, newspaper]
    # print(test_data)    #convert value data into numpy array
    # test_data = np.array(test_data).astype(np.float)    #reshape array
    # test_data = test_data.reshape(1,-1)
    # print(test_data)    #open file
    # file = open("lr_model.pkl","rb")    #load trained model
    # trained_model = joblib.load(file)    #predict
    # prediction = trained_model.predict(test_data)
    prediction = "hello"
    return prediction
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have added a call to your function before the rendering. I just return a string here just to demonstrate how you could set it up. I also commented the core functionality -i miss some libs- and make it to just return a value.

This works. So now when you click the button you will get:

```
Prediction is hello
```

in your browser. Can you build on this example?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've included the landing page html which takes in 3 input values and provides the "Predict" button. The intention is that the predict() method is only called after that predict button is pressed, which invokes the predict.html template. By that time I think my_prediction variable should be available to be passed on, or at least any hardcoded variable I think should be able to be passed on, but the predict.html doesn't show anything. Or maybe I don't fully understand the logic of how Flask operates

Comment: Hello, I edited my answer by adding a working example (minimum). Have a look with this and try to build on it.

Comment: It works exactly as expected now! I've been trying to figure it our for a while. I appreciate it a lot!!